# Electronic levels of Cadmium I

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy

I am working on an assignment, and I have ran into a few issues. I tried asking my teacher, but he has been away and is not answering any E-Mails.
My problem is as follows:Considering Cadmium with $Z=48$ and a fundamental state configuration given by $[Kr]4d^{10}5s^{2}$. The Zeeman effect can be observed for electronic transitions in Cd I: $^{1}D_2$ to $^1{P}_1$, emitting red light (644 nm)

I now wish to find the spectroscopic notation and the energy of the configuration for given excited states. The first one is:

Cd I: $[Kr]4d^{10}5s5p$.

The spectroscopic notation is given by $n^{2s+1}L_{J}$, with $n$ the principal quantum number, $s$ the spin and $J$ the total angular momentum. I am dealing only with electrons, so $s$ will be $\frac{1}{2}$. In this case the outermost electron is in a "p" shell, so it has angular momentum $l=0,1$. Thus, the total angular momentum, $J$, will be $$J=L+S=\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}$$ Here I have omitted the negative cases, as that is what my teacher did in class (but I dont quite understand why).

Now the energy configuration: We saw in class that the energy difference can be observed from the Biot-Savat law in an electron orbiting the proton, and we got the result that:

$$\Delta H=\frac{e^{2}Z}{r^3}\frac{g_s}{2M_e^{2}c^{2}}(L S)$$

from this,we can find that

$$\Delta H=\frac{K\hbar^2}{2}(j(j+1)-L(L+1)-s(s+1))$$

This should be how I find the energy, but im not sure what value I have to take for $r$, as I don't know what the radius of the orbits are for 5p electrons in cadmium. I tried using the Bohr radius, but it got me a value that is way too high.

Also, this formula doesn't seem to differentiate between the energies of a $2d$ or a $5d$ shell, which doesn't make sense to me. Why could this be?

Comment: The radius will be a lot different for a 5d vs. 2d orbital.

Comment: What is $K$ in your last formula? Why are you asking what to use for $r$ when your last formula doesn’t have an $r$ in it?

Comment: K is just all the constants from the previous equation, which includes r